# jQuery Adding a css class to a link when clicked

Tags: jquery, css, class, onclick, onmousedown

I have the current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('ul.products-slideshow-thumbs li a').bind("mousedown", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("current");
});
</script>

<ul class="products-slideshow-thumbs">
  <li><a href="#"><img src="product-slides/thumbs/1.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="product-slides/thumbs/2.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="product-slides/thumbs/3.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

But it's not working properly (basically, nothing happens).
Any suggestions? (I'm afraid I'm fairly new to jQuery/JavaScript.)  Thank you!

Comment: It works OK here: http://jsfiddle.net/d4FMB/

Comment: If you are running the script in that order, than it will not work as DOM is not ready yet. Move all those Javascript codes below HTML or try wrapping with .ready function of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){   
   $('ul.products-slideshow-thumbs li a').click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("current");
    });
  });
</script>

<ul class="products-slideshow-thumbs">
  <li><a href="#"><img src="product-slides/thumbs/1.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="product-slides/thumbs/2.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="product-slides/thumbs/3.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: +1 I'm pretty sure the problem is that the script is running before the HTML elements have been created.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  And @StriplingWarrior: You're right, I was placing this in the middle of the page for testing, instead of placing the js between the header tags.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code and it seemed to work for me. Have you also tried the `.click()` jquery method?

http://jsfiddle.net/jordanlewis/X6mn5/