# Swap class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, onclick, swap

I've been trying to figure out how I'm supposed to change a class of an element when you click it.

At the moment i have two classes (cOpen and cClosed). When you open the page the div is set to 'cClosed'.

```
<div id="camera" class="cClosed" onClick="cameraToggle('weekLoaderWrapper', 'cameraContainer');">Kamera</div></a>
```

The things within onClick is not relevant to my question btw..

I've also put this script in the code

```
$('#camera').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('cOpen');
    $(this).toggleClass('cClosed');
});
```

What I want it to do is to when you press the "camera"-div the class simply swaps to cClosed instead of cOpen, and vice verse when you click it again. This isn't working atm.

My problem is how i'm supposed to "toggle" the div so it swaps the class of the "camera"-div.

Comment: where are you putting your `$("#camera").click(...)` ? in a `$(document).ready(function(){...});` or similar construct?

Comment: Lots of other questions around [just like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545553/jquery-adding-a-css-class-to-a-link-when-clicked)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using two classes? Use one class to identify the open and none to denote closed.

```
$('#camera').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('cOpen');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work :S. http://ngmat.site90.net/matsedel/ is the site I'm working on. I guess you can check for error there.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as:

```
$('div').click(
    function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('cClosed cOpen');
    });​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kcB32/1/).

Though I second [Starx's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10215572/82548) in this; but it's your HTML.

Reference:

- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).